# How to fix duplicate item in android tool bar ,(need to remove menu items on toolbar)?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I am trying to hide a few of menu item located in android toolbar. 
I have implement this code :

```
MenuItem beaconIconMenuItem = 
toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_beacon);
                beaconIconMenuItem.setVisible(false);
```

When I try to compile the code, there is no error, but instead of removing the toolbar it is hown twice.

This is my source code:

```
 private void setupToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



        if (getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("PNM e-Reader")){
            toolbar.setTitle("My Books");



        }else {
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.booklist_drawer_mylibrary));



        }
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);


        // if kpm app , hide beacon icon on toolbar
        if (getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")){
            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);
            MenuItem beaconIconMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_beacon);
            beaconIconMenuItem.setVisible(false);


            //if kpm app , hide filter icon on toolbar
        }else if
                (getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")){
                toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);
                MenuItem filterMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.common_menu_filter);
                filterMenuItem.setVisible(false);

            //if kpm app , hide new collection selection under settings icon on toolbar

        }else  if
                (getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")){
                toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);
                MenuItem newcollectionMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_addtab);
                newcollectionMenuItem.setVisible(false);


        }
```

And this is the xml file to related java class:

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/booklist_mylibrary_menu_beacon"
        android:title="@string/beacon_switch"
        android:id="@+id/common_menu_filter"
        android:title="@string/common_filter"
        android:id="@+id/booklist_mylibrary_menu_addtab"
        android:title="@string/booklist_tab_add"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item

</menu>
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: how to fix the code, because the code will replicate the item on toolbar that should be remove

Comment: Check answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating the menu twice. Once before the if statement and once inside the if statement

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);
```

You are calling this before the if statements and inside the if statements.

Remove it from the if statement.

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    if (resources.getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")) {
        MenuItem beaconIconMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_beacon);
        beaconIconMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        //if kpm app , hide filter icon on toolbar
    } else if (resources.getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")) {
        MenuItem filterMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.common_menu_filter);
        filterMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        //if kpm app , hide new collection selection under settings icon on toolbar
    } else if (resources.getString(R.string.app_name).equalsIgnoreCase("KPM")) {
        MenuItem newcollectionMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_addtab);
        newcollectionMenuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Look's like your only doing `else-if` on `kpm` so I will just convert it to a switch and clean up your code. now it should look like

```
private void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).toLowerCase();
    toolbar.setTitle(appName.equals("pnm e-reader") ? "My Books" : getString(R.string.booklist_drawer_mylibrary));
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);
    switch (appName) {
        case "kpm":
            Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();

            MenuItem beaconIconMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_beacon);
            MenuItem filterMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.common_menu_filter);
            MenuItem newcollectionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.booklist_mylibrary_menu_addtab);

            beaconIconMenuItem.setVisible(false);
            newcollectionMenuItem.setVisible(false);
            filterMenuItem.setVisible(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works but only for hiding menu_beacon, if I want to remove for common_filter and tab_add,  should I do the same steps by removing :toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.booklist_mylibrary_menu);